# Would VS Would Have PP

Tags: future-in-past

I have some problems to understand the true usage of “would” and “would have pp”. I have already reviewed many forums and websites, but I have not managed to come to any conclusion. For instance, in these sentences:

1- People in the area had never seen this phenomenon before, but they also reported that there less mosquitoes than they **would have expected**, given the amount of standing water.
Why “would have expected”? And to be precise: Why not “would expect”?

2- *Another reason to use a hybrid format is when you want to highlight skills and achievements from earlier in your career that **would otherwise be buried** at the bottom of the second page of your resume*
Why “would be buried”? And to be precise: Why not “would have been buried”?

3- *Without SuperM, I **would never have trusted** my memory to keep a word for 10 days.*
Why “would never trusted”? And to be precise: Why not “would never trust”?

4- *People in the area had never seen this phenomenon before, but they also reported that there less mosquitoes than they **would have expected**, given the amount of standing water.*
Why “would have expected”? And to be precise: Why not “would expect”?

5- *My life **would have been** completely empty without you.*
Assuming ‘without you=if you were not in my life”, is this sentence correct as well: My life would be completely empty without you (if you were not in my life)

Please forgive me if my question is a bit basic.

Answer (score 3):

It's a question of whether you're talking about something that happened in the past, or something that is happening presently.

> There are fewer mosquitos than I *would* expect. (The expectation is happening right now.)
>
> There are fewer mosquitos than I *would have* expected, but now I know it's because they just sprayed the area with mosquito repellent.  (The expectation happened in the past.)

The *would* version is the more generic of the two, and can be used both for past and present pretty interchangeably.  The *would have* version strongly implies the past.

When dealing with hypothetical situations, the wording affects whether you're talking about past or future.

> My life *would have* been completely empty without you.   (talking about a hypothetical *past* in which the person was never in your life)
>
> My life *would* be completely empty without you.   (talking about a hypothetical *future* in which the person is not in your life any longer)

Again, the *would* version can be used fairly interchangeably for both past or future, but the *would have* version strongly implies the past.

Comment: And may I ask, in this sentence:

"There are fewer mosquitoes than I **would have expected**"

if we can say instead: "There are fewer mosquitoes than I **was** expected"?

Comment: What about these two: There are fewer mosquitos than I expected / There are fewer mosquitos than I had expected? @Lynn

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng - Those are equivalent IMHO, and both describe expectations in the past.  The 'had' is redundant.