# What tense to use when reporting something which has never been true or never happened?

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense, indirect-speech

> The report said that years ago city planners had planned to build a facility that **turns** salt water into fresh water, but financial woes made that impossible.

In this sentence should turned be used instead of turns?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am new to the site so please forgive me for my lack of experience.

Comment: The case posed differs from those discussed in at least the more immediately linked earlier questions, in that the desalinization never actually occurred; and a situation or condition contrary to fact can be an occasion for backshifting verb tense, even apart from the reporting of past statement.

Comment: @hale After reviewing the questions and answers, I’m not completely satisfied with their treatment of this topic. I therefore hope that you get a good answer to your question.

Comment: You might be interested in the topic of **backshift**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only form of the verb that does full justice to both the past-ness of the planning and the non-reality of the desalinization is *would have turned.* On this construction *(would have* plus past participle), [see this former question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128051).

Comment: I’m not sure I’m completely following you. Are you only saying that *would have turned* would sound better, or are you also saying that *turns* is actually ungrammatical?

Comment: I think *turned* works fine, because *had planned* already indicates that it never happened. (But *would have turned* works fine, too.)

Comment: If the condition in the subordinate clause is still true at the time it gets reported, then it is ok to retain the present tense.  *She told me her brother writes well.*  It seems to me that if you change *writes* to either of *wrote* or *would write*, then you change the meaning.

Comment: @tchrist, the desalinization plant that was never even built does not continue to turn salt water into fresh, never having begun to do so--in which case yes, *turns* is grammatically quite unsuitable. That the present tense is acceptable where the predication remains true in the present is irrelevant, for the predication in question (that the "facility . . . turns salt water into fresh water") is not and never has been true.